# How do I create code in VBA/macros for birthday notice?

Tags: excel, vba

For instance, I have a sheet which contains names of 100+ people. In column H I have their birth dates. What will the code look like if I want to find out which friend's birthday is today? Of course the macro will need to run through that column and see if today's date matches one with in column H. I have very little experience with VBA/Macros. Please and thank you for your help.

Comment: Conditional formatting might be a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

This code will put a message on I column if someone' birthday is today as per H column. (Assuming G column has person's name.

```
Sub BirthdayAlert()
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim varArray As Variant
Dim lb As Long
Dim i As Integer

    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
    lastRow = ws.Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    varArray = Application.Transpose(ws.Range("H2:H" & lastRow).Value)
    lb = LBound(varArray)

    For i = LBound(varArray) To UBound(varArray)
        If IsDate(varArray(i)) Then
           If CDate(varArray(i)) = Date Then
              varArray(i) = "Today is Your Birthday " & Range("G2").Offset(i).Value
            Else
                varArray(i) = ""
           End If
        End If
    Next i

    If UBound(varArray) > 0 Then
        ws.Range("I2:I" & lastRow).Value = Application.Transpose(varArray)
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's something simple for it:

```
Sub birthdayThing()
    Dim rng As Range

    For Each rng In Range("H2:H100")
       If CDate(rng) = Date Then rng.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Birthday"
    Next rng
End Sub
```